# fix laravel 5 session expiring after refresh or going on another page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel default Auth. When I login into my website all works great. When I try to refresh or go to another page (still using Auth middleware) my session is expired, I'm directly logged-out and I must login again. How can I fix this so I remain logged in when refreshing the page or browsing to another?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth changing (app/session.php):

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session'
```

To something relevant to your app/website as it is reset every time the cache is compiled

Comment: i didn't get this can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Check sesssion config file in:

```
config/session.php
```

If you have

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')
```

check the permissions on sessions folder that default is 'storage/framework/sessions':

```
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions')
```

Comment: i'm working on my localhost. still getting this issue :(

Comment: Have you set  777 permissions in storage folder?

Comment: yeah i tried this command chmod -R 777 {appname/storage} but still getting this issue

Comment: And can you see the files in storage/framework/sessions once you enter the site? Maybe you can change the driver to "cookies" and see what happen

Comment: yes i can see. its creating a new files when i enter the site. :(

Comment: i changed driver to cookies(native) and database also still getting issue. :(

Comment: I know it's 2019~2020, but i'm facing the exact same issue and i've done everything possible to get this fixed, how did you solve it, do you remember?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to set a higher lifetime in `config/session.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Note with `expire_on_close` if you set this to true, session will expire when a browser is closed