# Why does Laravel log out when I refresh the page after logging in?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7

Everyone thanks. I fixed this problem. The source of the problem;

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">Çıkış Yap</a>
```

this code line. Auth::logout() function. nobody clicks but this works. I will use the route.

---

I am using Laravel 7 library. I log in from the login page and go to the home page. However, when I refresh the page, it seems that the session has ended.

Because I use @auth and @guest in blade template. For the menu layout.

*LoginController page;*

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

*HomeController*

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
```

*web.php*

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

*and this layout.app.blade page*

```
@guest
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('login') }}">Giriş Yap</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('register') }}">Hizmet Ver</a>
@endguest

@auth
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profilim</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">Çıkış Yap</a>
@endauth
```

I hope you understand what I mean. I am logging in, yes the menu works correctly. But when the page is refreshed, it appears to be logged out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582926/fix-laravel-5-session-expiring-after-refresh-or-going-on-another-page/32583117 check this link

Comment: This is old version Laravel. I'm now using 7 version. Default settings.

Comment: I know but you can check these `session.php` file in `app/config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Auth::logout()` in `href` in second `<a>` tag at `@auth` block. When each time the page is refreshed, `Auth::logout()` is called and it is logging out from current session.
Please remove the `Auth::logout()` from there and add the logout URL. It will work.

```
@auth
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profilim</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}">Çıkış Yap</a>
@endauth
```